# Computing Fourier Series and it's modes of convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series

**Problem:**

(a) Let $f(x)=\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $-\pi\le x\lt0$ } \\
0, & \text{if $0\le x\lt\pi$ }
\end{cases}$
Show that it's Fourier series is $\frac12+\frac1\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{((-1)^n-1)}{n}\sin(nx).$

(b) Explain why this series converges in mean to $f$.

(c) What can you say about the pointwise and uniform convergence of this series?

(d) Why are the coefficients of the cosine terms all zero?

**Attempt:**

(a), (d): Recall that the Fourier Series is given by: $f(x)=\frac{a_0}2+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(a_k\cos(kx)+b_k\sin(kx))$ where $k\in\mathbb N$. Here, $a_k$ and $b_k$ are given by $\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(kx)dx$ and $\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin(kx)dx$ respectively.

Notice that for $a_k$ we have that:

$$a_k=\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(kx)dx=\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^0 \cos(kx)dx+0=\frac1\pi[\frac1k\sin(kx)]_{-\pi}^0=0$$

Which highlights why the coefficients of the cosine terms are all zero. As such, our Fourier Series will be given in terms of sine functions. We now determine $b_k$.

$$b_k=\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin(kx)dx=\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^0 \sin(kx)dx=\frac1\pi\left[-\frac1k\cos(kx)\right]_{-\pi}^0=\frac1\pi\left(-\frac1n+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)$$

Now, $a_0$ is given by $\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)dx=1$. So that on putting this all together we do indeed get that the Fourier Series is given by:

$$\frac12+\frac1\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{((-1)^n-1)}{n}\sin(nx)$$

(b),(c): Here is where I am running into difficulty, and am unsure whether or not the approach I am taking is the right one.

For (b) I think I should compute $\|(\frac12+\frac1\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{((-1)^n-1)}{n}\sin(nx))-1\|_2^2$ and then $\|(\frac12+\frac1\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{((-1)^n-1)}{n}\sin(nx))-0\|_2^2$ for when $x\in[-\pi,0)$ and $x\in[0,\pi)$ respectively, and show that they approach zero in each case. Besides needing to confront the square of a an infinite sum in each case, it seems that I am left with an overhanging $\frac12$ in each case? Where am I going wrong?

For (c) I am not too sure, being quite rusty. What tests should I be using the test the different convergences of this series? Does establishing (b) firstly let me deduce something about these two other modes of convergence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by "convergence in mean" you mean "convergence in $L^2$", that's given by [Riesz-Fischer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Fischer_theorem) in general. So, you don't have to work with your particular example, you just need to find the Fourier coefficients (which you did).

The [Dirichlet-Dini Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence) shows that the series converges to $f$ at all points other than $0$ and the end points.

Since $f$ is  not continuous, the convergence cannot be uniform (because a uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous).

Comment: The FS will not converge to $f$ at $-\pi$ either.

Comment: I agree, and I edited that in. Note, though, that the way the question is phrased $-\pi$ is not in the domain of $f$.

Comment: I thought $f$ was defined on $[-\pi,\pi).$

Comment: So did I, and that would have been the standard thing to do.